# jar command doesn't run in bash script, but run's when I execute it manually

Tags: linux, jar, zip, centos

trying to debug not working script. So the script is in `/etc/init.d/` permissions are correct and owned by `root`. The part of the script that is not working:

```
mkdir -p $UNZIPPED_FOLDER
cd $UNZIPPED_FOLDER
echo "Im here `pwd`"
jar xvf $path
#unzip $path -d $UNZIPPED_FOLDER
```

just for references:

```
path="/ebs/data.zip"
UNZIPPED_FOLDER="/tmp/unzipped_data"
```

When I run the script I can see it gets executed up to the line `Im here /tmp/unzipped_data`
but nothing happens after it.

I was thinking my variable is wrong , but if I run it manually `jar xvf $path` (assuming I did something like `echo $path` before in the script) then it works.

I also checked `which jar` which gave me `/usr/bin/jar`.

Also everything is running under `root`

Comment: What's in $path? the jar file is there right?

Comment: Yes, check to make sure `$path` is actually set at that point. Running the script with `/bin/sh -x /etc/init.d/script` will force the shell to print each command it executes, so you can see exactly what it's actually doing at every step of the way. It may help here.